# Speed up angle calculation for each x,y point in a matrix

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I have a 3-d Numpy array `flow` as follows:

```
flow = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(720,1280,2))
# Suppose flow[0] are x-coordinates. flow[1] are y-coordinates.
```

Need to calculate the angle for each x,y point. Here is how I have implemented it:

```
def calcAngle(a):
    assert(len(a) == 2)
    (x, y) = a
    # angle_deg = 0
    angle_deg = np.angle(x + y * 1j, deg=True)
    return angle_deg

fangle = np.apply_along_axis(calcAngle, axis=2, arr=flow) 
# The above statement takes 14.0389318466 to execute
```

The calculation of angle at each point takes `14.0389318466 seconds` to execute on my Macbook Pro.

Is there a way I could speed this up, probably by using some matrix operation, rather than processing each pixel one at a time.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`numpy.arctan2()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) to get the angle in radians, and then convert to degrees with [`numpy.rad2deg()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rad2deg.html):

```
fangle = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(flow[:,:,1], flow[:,:,0]))
```

On my computer, this is a little faster than Divakar's version:

```
In [17]: %timeit np.angle(flow[...,0] + flow[...,1] * 1j, deg=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 44.5 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(flow[:,:,1], flow[:,:,0]))
10 loops, best of 3: 35.4 ms per loop
```

A more efficient way to use `np.angle()` is to create a complex view of `flow`.  If `flow` is an array of type `np.float64` with shape `(m, n, 2)`, then `flow.view(np.complex128)[:,:,0]` will be an array of type `np.complex128` with shape `(m, n)`:

```
fangle = np.angle(flow.view(np.complex128)[:,:,0], deg=True)
```

This appears to be a smidge faster than using `arctan2` followed by `rad2deg` (but the difference is not far above the measurement noise of `timeit`):

```
In [47]: %timeit np.angle(flow.view(np.complex128)[:,:,0], deg=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 35 ms per loop
```

Note that this might not work if `flow` was creating as the tranpose of some other array, or as a slice of another array using steps bigger than 1.

Comment: Nice! Though this doesn't seem to work with complex numbers, neither is OP's sample data.

Comment: If the input was complex, the OP's method wouldn't work, so I think we don't have to worry about that case.

Comment: I guess that depends on your definition of "work". :)  My response should have been "The data is *flow*.  Why would a flow have complex x and y components?  What is the meaning of the angle between a complex x component and a complex y component?  My guess is there is no use-case for complex inputs, so we don't have to worry about that possibility."

Comment: Yeah as OP mentioned those are x and y coordinates. So, I guess we don't need to worry given the context :)

Answer (score 4):

[`numpy.angle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.angle.html) supports vectorized operation. So, just feed in the first and second column slices to it for the final output, like so -

```
fangle = np.angle(flow[...,0] + flow[...,1] * 1j, deg=True)
```

Verification -

```
In [9]: flow = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(720,1280,2))

In [17]: out1 = np.apply_along_axis(calcAngle, axis=2, arr=flow)

In [18]: out2 = np.angle(flow[...,0] + flow[...,1] * 1j, deg=True)

In [19]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[19]: True
```

Runtime test -

```
In [10]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(calcAngle, axis=2, arr=flow)
1 loop, best of 3: 8.27 s per loop

In [11]: %timeit np.angle(flow[...,0] + flow[...,1] * 1j, deg=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 47.6 ms per loop

In [12]: 8270/47.6
Out[12]: 173.73949579831933
```

**`173x+`** speedup!

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had already tried the matrix solution you specified, and was getting some error. Maybe I made a mistake earlier..